# Trouble with RtfWriter2 (iText)

Tags: java, itext, rtf

I am trying to create document using iText. I am using Eclipse IDE. I've imported the jar files (itextpdf-5.2.1.jar and itext-xtra-5.2.1.jar).

However RtfWriter2 is not being recognised as a class.

```
Document doc = new Document();
RtfWriter2 writer = new RtfWriter2();
RtfWriter2.getInstance(doc,new FileOutputStream("testRTFdocument.rtf"));
```

Can someone help me in figuring out what I am missing. I am very new to iText.

Answer (score 0):

RTF support has been dropped since [iText 5.0.0](http://itextpdf.com/history/?branch=50&node=500). The last version of iText to include RTF functionnality is iText 2.1.7. Please note that iText 2.x is not maintained anymore, so you should not expect any bugfix if any is needed.